# Azure Web Job Missing from the list

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am currently facing one issue with my Azure Webjobs. I have created custom build tasks in TFS that build my solution and copy the files of 5 different console projects to app_data/jobs/triggered/MyProjectName then zip them into 1 file and deploy into my staging slot of my Azure Web App. When I navigate to the slot I can see 4 out of 5 jobs. When I log in to the FTP location I can see all 5 jobs. What is the possible issue, is there a limit on the number of jobs ? I do not think it is the webjob name as I have one with longer name and it is showing fine. The name format is following xxxx.webjobs.projectname no numbers, no special characters. I have tried to rename the webjob did not help.

Comment: Does restarting the site help? Can you share your web app name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a silly mistake that I made, when I publish to azure I was publishing both Release and Debug folder. The Release folder was my leftover from my previous test with no files. I have removed the Release folder and it all started working. Perhaps, if Azure by default will use Release folder and does not find anything in that folder and if there is Debug folder it should go to debug and leave a note in logs that Debug is currently being used? I hope that helps!